# On $\lambda$-adic Galois representation associated to Hilbert modular form

Tags: nt.number-theory

Taylor shows that for a Hilbert moduar form of parallel weight 2, if we let $\rho$ be the associated $\ell$-adic Galois representation, then there is a $\ell$-divisible group $H$ such $\rho|_{G_\lambda}$ for $\lambda|\ell$ is isomorphic to the $\ell$-adic Tate module of $H$. What about the case for general weight?

Comment: What is the question? Is it "Is there a $p$-divisible group"? If so, the answer is "no, because the Hodge-Tate weights are wrong" (except in parallel weight 1, when there is an etale $p$-divisible group).

Comment: There was some confusion between $p$'s and $\ell$'s in the question; I cleaned it up. I hope I didn't mistake the intent of the question.